# how to enter the string value in a particular cell of DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hello Guys ,
              how to enter the string value in a particular cell of DataGrid in WPF .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more precise. Are you talking about an editable cell or do you want to do it programatically? Is your cell bound to a view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do it this way

```
void OurGrdEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
 {

       DataRowView dRowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
       string sName = dRowView.Row["columnName"].ToString();
 }
```